# how to integrate the Facebook in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, facebook

I am trying to integrate the Facebook into my application, but when i am run the application it showing below message.

[image]

please tell me where i did the mistake.

i fallowed the 
[raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/77/how-to-post-on-facebook-with-your-iphone-app) link

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checkout this link

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

This is the official link for Facebook ios sdk ,It shows all the steps to integrate facebook and also has 2 working examples link

Answer (score 0):

It might be the API, in which case you would want to [download the newest one](http://github.com/facebook/facebook-iphone-sdk/). Also, try getting your API and "Secret" keys again, they might be incorrect. Hope this helps!